# controllable for mimo system in matlab

Tags: matlab, controls, state-space, canonical-form

I have a MIMO state space system. I need to obtained a controllability canonical realisation in matlab. How can I do it?. I only know to find a controllable and observable on SISO system. can anyone help me?

Comment: Ask this question on engineering stack exhange. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @willpower2727 There are engineers here too!

Comment: @norul to clarify, do you mean the Controllability Canonical Realization Matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes your system is controllable (you can use the `ctrb` function to check or CHT).

You can use the [canon function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/canon.html) to obtain the [controllability canonical matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(systems)#Canonical_realizations) of the linear dynamic system model stored into `sys`. Please note that the way Matlab defines it may not be the same as what you define it to be. Check it's definition on the function definition page.

```
canon(sys,type)
```

Comment: yes..i mean controllability canonical realization matrix.. thank you for helping me. i will try the canon function. thank you so much @krisdestruction

Comment: @norul Can you kindly accept the answer if it's correct?

Comment: yes.. i will try to find how the canon function work in order to obtain the controllability matrix..

Comment: I had try the canon function, but there has error 'the matrix is nearly singular'. so, i think my system cannot use the canon function or the system not controllable.

Comment: If  your system is not controllable, then no canonical form exists... did you check the controllability of your system?

Comment: Use the `ctrb` function to check controllability, or use CHT and `rank`
http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ctrb.html?refresh=true

Comment: i think my system is not controllable. i got 78 number of uncontrollable states.

Comment: In that case, then the canonical form just doesn't exist XD you have to add more inputs to be able to use canon. I'm not sure how else I can help you here :/

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you (especially the `ctrb` part), can you consider accepting my answer?